# Hibernate Interface mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have been working on Hibernate for a couple of years now but looks like I am missing some fundamentals.
In core Java we learned that any variable declared in interface is implicitly constant and there is no way you can create a interface that has variables in it. That is it will only contain constants. 
So my question is, when we map an interface to a table, what do we achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shall achieve implicit polymorphism through this.The advantage of is that we can get the records of generalized level without writing union query or making changes in mapping. Say we have Car interface with two concrete classes CarA and CarB. Then writing

```
session.createCriteria(Car.class).list();
```

we will get all the records of two concrete classes. It will check all subclasses and fire separate queries and provide combined result.